# Movie Relation Database Design

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I'm creating a movie information database but stuck at designing relational table between 1 movie with the others.

For example: Avengers is a prequel of Avengers 2, but should I store the reverse relation (sequel) in my database? And should I separated the relationship into separated table? Currently I have 3 alternative, but which is really the best practice for designing database?

**Alternative 1: Two tables with pair of relationship stored inside the relation mapping**

```
Movies: id, title, ...
Relation_maps: id, movie_id, related_movie_id, relation_text, reverse_relation_text
```

So, if I have 2 movies: Avengers, and Avengers 2. I'll have one relation mapping with relation_text of "prequel" and reverse relation text of "sequel"

**Alternative 2: Split relation into separated table and store the reverse relationship as an id of the table itself**

```
Movies: id, title, ...
Relation_maps: id, movie_id, related_movie_id, relation_id
Relations: id, reverse_relation_id (self-refer to id), relation_text
```

Relationship text, will be stored in another table with reverse relationship stored as an self-referring id. So in relations table, It'll become like this:

```
  id | reverse_relation_id | relation_text
  1  | 2                   | prequel
  2  | 1                   | sequel
```

**Alternative 3: Split relation into separated table and reverse relationship will be shown through conditional code**

```
Movies: id, title, ...
Relation_maps: id, movie_id, related_movie_id, relation_id
Relations: id, relation_text
```

Same with alternative 2, except reverse relationship will be shown through conditinal statement in view code. If this is better, should I really split the relation text or combine it in relation_maps table?

Are there any better alternatives in terms of performance and best practice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
Relations

id        name
 1        Star Wars


Relations_Detail

relation_id  movie_id   relation_type    sequence
          1        40   prequel                 0
          1        50   prequel                 1
          1        60   prequel                 2
          1        10   debut                   3
          1        20   sequel                  4
          1        30   sequel                  5
```

You would have a multi-column primary key of (relation_id, movie_id).

Comment: I didn't really get what you mean. Why does relations table is the same with movies table with only name of the movie in it? And what does order used for?

Comment: @deka, you're going to want to name your relations, and you can't use auto-increment to create new ids in the detail table, but you can use auto-increment in the relations table. Also, the "sequence" column allows you to list the movies in order simply.

Comment: Oh, i get it now. How about the reverse relation? For example in your case if movie_id 40 is star wars, and movie_id 50 is star wars 2? I think, if I use it this way, there'll be too many relation_details and redundancy.

Comment: @deka, what is this reverse relation? Try querying an unknown number of records using the linked list approach.